# How can I drill through concrete blocks to allow drainage from my backyard?

Tags: concrete, drill, drainage, concrete-block

My back yard has a brick floor and is surrounded by a concrete block wall. In heavy rains, the yard pools with rain water. How do I go about cutting drain holes in the wall or floor?

Comment: There is no dirty in the backyard?  All the way to the earth's core?  We need pictures.

Comment: Why does she think it's a problem?

Comment: I doubt it is legal to divert your run-off onto someone else's property.

Comment: Drill + Masonry bit will easily drill through concrete blocks.

Comment: @DMoore There's only *dirty* in the backyard if you have a privacy fence, otherwise the neighbors call the cops. This is **not** the place for *those* types of pictures.

Comment: @bib It's a problem, because she's standing in ankle deep water whenever she goes in the back yard.

Comment: @mike Water is a lawless entity, and can go wherever it wants to go.

Comment: @DA01 That sounds like the beginnings of an answer.

Comment: Her backyard is built like a poorly constructed pool.  Why wouldn't she be standing in water?

Comment: @Tester101 - if she goes in the backyard she will be a dirty girl.  And there are laws on water run-off at the municipality level.  Try to regrade your land in my town just a little bit and you might need several engineers to sign off on it.  I dug up my french drains in the middle of the night to hide the work from neighbors.

Comment: @Tester101 I think that's the entire answer. :)

Comment: @Tester101 that is funny. yep water obeys only the laws of physics.

Answer (score 1):

Pictures might change the answer but...

Is the terrain outside the block wall your property?  Is the elevation lower than your backyard?  If you answered yes to both of those questions I'd say strategically and carefully, maybe hire someone, remove blocks or pieces of block. Drilling holes does not sound like adequate drainage but if they were big enough it might work.

I would probably remove a section of brick at the lowest point in the yard and dig a large pit.  Line the pit with some type of filter fabric that will keep fine soil particles from passing through and then almost fill the hole with large gravel. (Here in this part of the US we would use what is called blue stone)  Cover with the same fabric.  Install a porous grate or cover of some sort over it.  You could even cover it with soil and plant grass or something else if you liked.  Figuring out what survives there might take trial and error. This will give the water somewhere to escape to while it slowly drains out of your yard.